Openai NotFoundError
I tried to make an API connection from QlikSense for Llama3 model, but when I try to test the connection I get the error: 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found'.
I used:
URL: http://localhost:5000/v1/chat/completions
Method: POST
Request body:
{
    "messages": [
      {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "Hello! My name is Dumbo. What is my name?"
      }
    ],
    "mode": "instruct",
    "instruction_template": "Alpaca"
  }

Any idea?

This question from April looks similar in that the asker is querying Llama and getting a 404 error even though they think that the request URL is correct. It's not clear how they solved the problem.

Look in your server logs to see what file it is trying to load.
